# Sum column as an additional column sql

Tags: sql

I am trying to work with a dataset that has distinct columns. I am looking at adding a column that provides sum of quantity against each row based on the Order ID. Please see below the input and desired output:

Input:

```
+----+---------+-----+----------+
| ID | OrderID | PID | Quantity |
+----+---------+-----+----------+
| 1  | 10248   | 11  | 12       |
+----+---------+-----+----------+
| 2  | 10248   | 42  | 10       |
+----+---------+-----+----------+
| 3  | 10248   | 72  | 5        |
+----+---------+-----+----------+
| 4  | 10249   | 14  | 9        |
+----+---------+-----+----------+
| 5  | 10249   | 51  | 40       |
+----+---------+-----+----------+
| 6  | 10250   | 41  | 10       |
+----+---------+-----+----------+
| 7  | 10250   | 51  | 35       |
+----+---------+-----+----------+
| 8  | 10250   | 65  | 15       |
+----+---------+-----+----------+
| 9  | 10251   | 22  | 6        |
+----+---------+-----+----------+
| 10 | 10251   | 57  | 15       |
+----+---------+-----+----------+
| 11 | 10251   | 65  | 20       |
+----+---------+-----+----------+
| 12 | 10252   | 20  | 40       |
+----+---------+-----+----------+
| 13 | 10252   | 33  | 25       |
+----+---------+-----+----------+
```

Desired output:

```
+----+---------+-----+----------+-------+
| ID | OrderID | PID | Quantity | Total |
+----+---------+-----+----------+-------+
| 1  | 10248   | 11  | 12       | 27    |
+----+---------+-----+----------+-------+
| 2  | 10248   | 42  | 10       | 27    |
+----+---------+-----+----------+-------+
| 3  | 10248   | 72  | 5        | 27    |
+----+---------+-----+----------+-------+
| 4  | 10249   | 14  | 9        | 49    |
+----+---------+-----+----------+-------+
| 5  | 10249   | 51  | 40       | 49    |
+----+---------+-----+----------+-------+
| 6  | 10250   | 41  | 10       | 60    |
+----+---------+-----+----------+-------+
| 7  | 10250   | 51  | 35       | 60    |
+----+---------+-----+----------+-------+
| 8  | 10250   | 65  | 15       | 60    |
+----+---------+-----+----------+-------+
| 9  | 10251   | 22  | 6        | 41    |
+----+---------+-----+----------+-------+
| 10 | 10251   | 57  | 15       | 41    |
+----+---------+-----+----------+-------+
| 11 | 10251   | 65  | 20       | 41    |
+----+---------+-----+----------+-------+
| 12 | 10252   | 20  | 40       | 65    |
+----+---------+-----+----------+-------+
| 13 | 10252   | 33  | 25       | 65    |
+----+---------+-----+----------+-------+
```

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592).
Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),
and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you didn't mention any RDBMS, this query below will almost work in most RDBMS. What the query does is it calculates the `Total` inside the subquery and joins the result in the original table itself.

```
SELECT  a.*,
        b.Total
FROM    TableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  OrderID, SUM(Quantity) Total
            FROM    TableName
            GROUP   BY OrderID
        ) b ON a.OrderID = b.OrderID
```

Here's a [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/113256/1).

However, if your RDBMS supports window function such as `SUM() OVER()`, this can be simple written as

```
SELECT  a.*,
        SUM(Quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY OrderID) Total
FROM    TableName a
```

Here's a [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/dee37/1).

Comment: Thanks heaps mate. Worked to perfection

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY`.

Try:

```sql
SELECT OrderID, COUNT(quantity) as total FROM table GROUP BY OrderID;
```